# How to draw vertical text on CGContext?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to draw a vertical text. I had tried different way to rotate string using **rotate by** but its not working

Here is my code

```
override func draw(with box: PDFDisplayBox, to context: CGContext) {

    let name = "Sunny"
    // Draw original content
    super.draw(with: box, to: context)

    // Draw rotated overlay string
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context)
    context.saveGState()

    let pageBounds = self.bounds(for: box)
    context.translateBy(x: pageBounds.size.width, y: 0)
    context.scaleBy(x: -1.0, y: -1.0)
    context.rotate(by: CGFloat.pi / 4.0)

    let string: NSString = name as! NSString
    let attributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.5),
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 64)
    ]

    string.draw(at: CGPoint(x:250, y:40), withAttributes: attributes)

    context.restoreGState()
    UIGraphicsPopContext()

}
```

How can i draw?

Comment: please add the box and context declaration. It is missing.

Comment: udated code please check

Comment: Did the below answer work ? If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can draw the vertical string using the below code, in which I have converted given string by adding `line separators` between the characters.

```
 override func draw(with box: PDFDisplayBox, to context: CGContext) {

        // Draw original content
        super.draw(with: box, to: context)

        // Draw rotated overlay string
        UIGraphicsPushContext(context)
        context.saveGState()

        let pageBounds = self.bounds(for: box)
        context.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: pageBounds.size.height)
        context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        context.rotate(by: CGFloat.pi / -60.0)

        // Convert string by adding line separators.
        let string = "Sunny".trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
        let asArray = Array(string)
        let verticalString = asArray.map { "\($0)" }.joined(separator: "\n")

        let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.4980392157, green: 0.4980392157, blue: 0.4980392157, alpha: 0.5),
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 64)
        ]

        verticalString.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 250, y: 40), withAttributes: attributes)

        context.restoreGState()
        UIGraphicsPopContext()

    }
```

[**Output of vertical string in PDF**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taNdQ.png)